# What could reinitialize COMP_WORDBREAKS after I set it in Git for Windows?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have some of my completion which use the `@` (as in `@group`) and I wished to remove it from `COMP_WORDBREAKS` but I have yet to understand what is *restoring* the `@`: I know fully that we should not tinker with `COMP_WORDBREAKS` and use `_get_comp_words_by_ref -n @`, but the version on Git for Windows 2.28.0.windows.1 (+bash 4.4.23(1)-release) does not work the same as the one on Linux (Gentoo + Bash 5 + app-shells/bash-completion 2.11).

I tried to add this to my `~/.bashrc` for Windows, which is sourced by `~/.bash_profile` and whose output is shown before the PS1 prompt:

```sh
echo "COMP_WORDBREAKS before:"; declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@/}"
echo "COMP_WORDBREAKS after:"; declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
export COMP_WORDBREAKS
```

However, this does not work as intended: the `@` is still present if I type the `declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS`  command:

```sh
COMP_WORDBREAKS before:
declare -- COMP_WORDBREAKS="
\"'><=;|&(:"
COMP_WORDBREAKS after:
declare -- COMP_WORDBREAKS="
\"'><=;|&(:"
# when I have first access to the TERM and that I can input the declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
$ declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
declare -- COMP_WORDBREAKS="@
\"'><=;|&(:"
```

Which is also shown in this screenshot (I removed identifying parts, but this is the "Git Bash" command bundled with Git for Windows):

[image: Terminal and COMP_WORDBREAKS]

As we can see, something (I suppose `bash`) is adding back the `@` but I can't find where or what do that.

- I've checking in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior) but I don't see where it would restore the `@`?
- I've also checked for file that could modify the `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, but did not see any conclusive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to hostname completion (`shopt -p hostcomplete`) which makes bash includes the `@` to complete (or split) host such as `user@hos`.

Seeing that, under Windows, the completion is pretty limited I disabled it:

- It uses (at least) `/etc/hosts` as source to complete
- Git for Windows `/etc/hosts` is void of any host.
- MSYS2 `/etc/hosts` seems to be a copy of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

I don't know (and it is unrelated to my question) why/when `/etc/hosts` is copied from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` but nevertheless this completion is rather useless in my case.

Comment: Just to be clear, hostcomplete can be disabled with the following command: "shopt -u hostcomplete". This command could be added to a .bashrc file for convenience.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done in 2020 :)

Answer (score -1):

It does not restore it. The error is the way you set/print the value.

In

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@/}"
```

you have correctly removed the `@`, and if you had simply done a

```
echo "COMP_WORDBREAKS after:"; declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
```

you would have seen that your changes are still here. But you decided to write it as

```
echo "COMP_WORDBREAKS after: $(declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS)"
```

which creates a child process for executing `declare`, and since you did not export the variable, the child process does not know that you have modified it, and creates its own, fresh version.

Comment: I'm obliged to say it don't work: I've used `declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS` to get the value as bash would like it, but before doing that I simply used `echo "COMP_WORDBREAKS after: $COMP_WORDBREAKS "`

Comment: Simple echo works the same. Just copy and paste the following: `COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@/}"; echo "$COMP_WORDBREAKS"`. Since you don't have any attributes set to the variable, `declare -p` is indeed not necessary. I just used it in my answer because you seemed to have liked it.

Comment: @NoDataFound : I see that you have edited your example, to match my answer. I have copied exactly your code and it works fine in my bash. See [this screenshot](https://ibb.co/MgtLyDR). While screenshots in questions are in general discouraged on SO, I think in your case it would help if you would also post a screenshot to prove that it does not work on your system.

Comment: Are you trying this in bashrc ? My question may not be clear to that point, but the COMP_WORDBREAKS is changed in the ~/.bashrc: the echo shows me the modification took place, and with/without exporting, we can see that typing `echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS` in the interactive shell (my ~/.bash_profile directly source .bashrc for that matter) hereafter produce the @.

Comment: It is no difference how you call the file where you put the commands into. I hope you manually did a  `source ~/.bashrc` **after changing it**, to test the effect in your shell. If this does not work, post a transscript of the this wit `set -x` turned on.

Comment: @NoDataFound : Actually, the screenshot you posted, proved that it worked, because the `@` appears only **after the command prompt** showed up again. From this I conclude that you did not source the file with the modifications; and, indeed, I don't see a `source` statement in your screenshot.

Comment: @NoDataFound : [Here](https://ibb.co/mc2fhXt) you have a screenshot showing the same thing going on when it's stored in a file. You can see from it step by step what is going on. I can't believe that we are discussing this trivial matter for such a long time!

Comment: The whole point of my question is that I want to modify `COMP_WORDBREAKS` as a part of the whole bash startup sequences because the `@` is problematic in my completions. So yes, sourcing `~/.bashrc` will work if I type `source ~/.bashrc`, but that's not what I want: what I want to know is *what is putting back the `@` after bash allows me to type any command?* All so that I can remove the offending part (for example, that could be some configuration specific to readline?). Beside, your screenshot does not look like standard Git for Windows, are you using it to test?

Comment: @NoDataFound : I'm using Cygwin, but this should make no difference. The interesting point is: Are other settings from your .bashrc applied? For example, if you put into your .bashrc the line  `foo=bar`, is the variable `foo` defined afterwards (`declare -p foo`)?

Comment: Yes it works. But comparing cygwin and MSYS2 (and Git for Windows, I'll have to try with a non Gfw MSYS2), while they share some commonalities, is perhaps not the good idea.